The geodesic exponential of a sum
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, $x\in M$ and $u,v\in T_xM$. I'm wondering what is known about $\exp_x(u+v)$. One obvious guess would be: let $V$ be the unique $\nabla^g$-parallel (here $\nabla^g$ is the Levi-Civita connection) vector field along the geodesic $t\mapsto \exp_x(tu)$ starting at $v$ and construct $\gamma(t):=\exp_{\exp_x(tu)}(tV(t))$. What is the relation between $\gamma(t)$ and $\exp_x(t(u+v))$? Is there any control (I guess depending on curvature) of how far are one from the other?

You should explain what kind of control you are hoping for, otherwise one can always get some estimates by using the triangle inequality.

@MoisheKohan I'm not sure what I'm looking for. I guess anything better than the triangle inequality would already be interesting? In Euclidean space, $\gamma(t)=\exp_x(t(u+v))$, which is way better than the triangle inequality. I was wondering if in curved spaces one could also have sharper bounds.
